# API response of FastAPI delete call

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi

Is it necessary to return anything when a delete is successful, or does merely specifying the status code in the decorator do everything? For example:

```
@app.delete("/posts/{id}", status_code=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
def delete_post(id: int):
    cursor.execute("DELETE FROM posts WHERE id=%s", (id,))
    conn.commit()
    return Response(status_code=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

Or, can I remote the `return` statement entirely?

```
@app.delete("/posts/{id}", status_code=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
def delete_post(id: int):
    cursor.execute("DELETE FROM posts WHERE id=%s", (id,))
    conn.commit()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can omit the return entirely, as the return code 204 is bound to not return any content. FastAPI replaces any content in 204, 304 and 1XX codes to `b””`.